# Screen orientation portrait for nano pc t4 board under Android 8.1

Tags: android, android-8.1-oreo

We have issue with screen orientation for the **nano pc t4** board running Android 8.1. On Landscape mode it works correctly, but in portrait mode it scales and shows as in the picture below with black corners:

[image: Photo of TV. Screen orientation is horizontal but Android app displayed vertically]

Currently we need to flip that as shown in the picture below with no black spaces:

[image: Photo of monitor with orientation rotated 90 degrees. App is displayed properly]

We have tested in multiple ways:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

and more variants. Can anyone help to set right configuration?

Comment: And by "black corners" do you mean the space that is the phone frame and the tablet itself?

Comment: Yes, exactly I mean that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `HDMI` output can be rotated, after unlocking the rotation lock:

```
adb shell root
adb shell remount
adb shell setprop persist.demo.hdmirotation portrait
adb shell setprop persist.demo.hdmirotationlock false
adb shell setprop persist.demo.singledisplay true
adb reboot
```

one can then set the wm's display geometry:

```
adb shell wm size 1080x1920
adb shell wm size 1920x1920
```

or switch the `user_rotation`:

```
settings put system user_rotation 1
settings put system user_rotation 3
```

the `NXP` community seems to be the [source](https://community.nxp.com/docs/DOC-97740).

Comment: I rooted my device and tried the above settings, but it still won't work. Any up-to-date solution?